# Magento cron doesnt send email at all

Tags: email, cron, smtp, send-mail, amazonses

I have a magento installation (1.9.2.3) on a Bitnami AWS instance, I am trying to use the SMTP Pro extension ( [source](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension) ) and use the Amazon SES feature. When I run the self-test it works and send the email from and to the configured emails.

But the magento installation cant send emails at all.

- I tried to run either cron.php or cron.sh , without any error, but without any apparent consequence.
- sendmail is installed and working
- Amazon SES credentials working

cronjob is irrelevant at this point since It doesnt do anything.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I think it'll work.

in the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Change

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

to

```
$mailer->send();
```

Comment: I saw the edit of your answer. Please do not recommend to change core files! The proper way to do this is via a rewrite.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, do you have any guide we can reach to make these changes ?, I am new in magento, so, I dont know, how to tell magento "dont use this, use the child class or the rewriteen class"

Comment: I've had the same problem, once I changed code as you described, everything seems to work just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Magento fails to send email to some domain as i had experience in past. in order to fix that i had used Smtp pro extension which fixes many of the issues as it uses smtp protocol

Comment: I am using the SMTP Pro extension, but I dont know how SMTP Pro handles the email queue